# Sharepoint 2010 - Datasheet view and 3 linked lists 1

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sharepoint

i created a workflow for item adding and item added. When i am adding the data to the list in datasheet view i am getting two mails like " item created and item updated ". why i am getting two mails.

Comment: Because your code send two mails? Seriously, how do you expect us to understand what's wrong if you don't give any details

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint can start a workflow when you create or update an item.
Since you have registered your workflow to run on both these events, it will be called when items are created or updated.

In quick edit mode this is a little tricky.

If you add a new item and add all the column values to the end, only a item added workflow will be triggered.

Everytime you focus on another item(row in the table) SharePoint will add/update the item.
This can cause your workflow to be called several times on updates in quick edit mode.

To avoid this, do not provide a quick edit mode on lists with update workflows.
If you must have the workflow, train your users to update all column values before moving to the next row.